# loop through object array and change the values

Tags: javascript

i am trying to loop through an object array (not sure if that is correct terminoledgy) and want to change the values to each key within the list.

example if I have a list of room1 = 0, room2 = 0, room3 = 0 and after i have looped through it will be room1 = 10, room2 = 10, room3 = 10.

I can do it with an array but will then loose the keys which is very helpfull when using the array in other parts of my program.

I understand this has been asked before but cannot see a solution to changing the values

My code below changes the values within the loop but the console log outside the loop shows room2 is still equal 0

Any help please or is this something that cannot be done

```js
temps = {room1:0, room2:0, room3:0};
const entries = Object.entries(temps);
for (i=0; i<3; i++){
  entries[i][1] = 10;
  console.log(entries[i]);
}
console.log("room2 = " + temps.room2);
```

Comment: entries is a different object than temps.

Comment: You already have the solution. You are changing values of "entries" and printing value of "temps". Instead of temps in the end use entries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just loop over the keys, you don't want `Object.entries` in this case because it's not giving you a reference into the original object:

```js
let temps = {room1:0, room2:0, room3:0};
for (let key in temps) {
  temps[key] = 10
}
console.log(temps)
console.log("room2 = " + temps.room2);
```

Comment: Thanks this works, i was getting a bit confused with using objects. I should be able to expand on this now. i will mark as correct when stack allows me to :)

Comment: It is important to remember that the `for...in` operator will loop through properties on the Prototype, as well. In your example, not much of a problem, but for this reason I almost always default to `Object.keys()` in these situations.

Comment: Yep @BenSteward that's definitely something to keep in mind if you're working with objects that inherit other enumerable properties. Although, at least the way I use prototypes, I often want those properties.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is you are just altering the `entries` array and that has no relationship back to the parent. Changing it does not change the parent since it is just a copy of the keys and values, it is not a reference to them.

So you need to alter the actual object. You can just iterate over the keys and alter the object. forEach loop makes it easy.

```js
const temps = {room1:0, room2:0, room3:0};
Object.keys(temps).forEach( function (key) {
  temps[key] = 10;
});
console.log(temps)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `for..in` to loop through an array , but in this case create a new array which hold s the new values(if the new values are all different). Then use `Object.keys` to get all the keys from the object ,and then retrieve and update the value in the main object

```js
const temps = {
  room1: 0,
  room2: 0,
  room3: 0
}

const newVals = [10, 20, 30]

Object.keys(temps).forEach((key, index) => {
  temps[key] = newVals[index]
})

console.log("room2 = " + temps.room2);
```

Comment: There were a few oddities. I upvoted and edited (pending review). `Object.keys` really should be the right answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an object keys with `Object.keys`. So the code is like it:

```
temps = {room1:0, room2:0, room3:0};
for (var key of Object.keys(temps)) {
    temps[key] = 10;
}
```

`Object.keys(temps)` returns an array of key values.
As George mentioned in the comments, you can do it in a simpler way without using `Objects.keys`. For that, you can use `in` instead of `of` keyword in the `for` and pass the `temps` object itself. Here is the code:

```
temps = {room1:0, room2:0, room3:0};
for (var key in temps) {
    temps[key] = 10;
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to do `Object.keys`, putting an object in a for loop will do that for you.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But I think `Object.keys` is more readable for a beginner than that. But I will add this to my answer. Thank for mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each key in the `temps` object, and update the temperature directly.

```js
temps = {room1:0, room2:0, room3:0};
for (k in temps) {
  temps[k] = 10
}
console.log("room2 = " + temps.room2);
```