# Convert each Array in a typescript object to a set

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, set

I am a beginner in Typescript, and I am looking for a neat way to convert all the arrays in an object to a set.

Input:

```
const inputObject = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [2, 2, 2], 'c': [3,3,2,4]};
```

Output

```
{'a': Set(3){1, 2, 3}, 'b': Set(1){2}, 'c': Set(3){2, 3, 4};
```

I know how to work on it iteratively key by key and get the solution. I am looking if I can do it more elegantly and modify the same `inputObject` instead of creating a new object.

Comment: What's the actual problem? What have you tried to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: or [loop through object array and change the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53397214/loop-through-object-array-and-change-the-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works, but not sure why it isn't working in StackOverflow's code editor.

You need to do the following

1. get the keys of the object you are trying to modify
2. Update each of them as `Set`.

```js
const inputObject = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [2, 2, 2], 'c': [3,3,2,4]};
console.log(inputObject);
Object.keys(inputObject).forEach(key => inputObject[key] = new Set(inputObject[key]));
console.log(inputObject);
```

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer and not the one from Paulo?

Comment: @Andreas I'm not sure, may be OP found interating keys more easily understandable.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code Works fine!

```
const inputObject = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [2, 2, 2], 'c': [3,3,2,4]};
 for (const key in inputObject ) {
    inputObject[key] = new Set(inputObject[key]);
    }
console.log(inputObject);
```